# checkbox detection with info using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have multiple document with checkbox (some are checked). **i need to fetch the info where the checkboxes are checked.**

i have checked for multiple approaches mentioned on stack but didn't found it relevant to what i am looking for.

looking for relevant info or article that would help me to approach this problem. are there any opensource OCR libraries that can serve the required purpose
any help would be highly appreciated..!

below is the approach i tried initially basis stack answer was to detect the contours but didn't served the purpose

```
import cv2

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('image_path')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and filter using contour area filtering to remove noise
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
AREA_THRESHOLD = 10
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < AREA_THRESHOLD:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 0, -1)

# Repair checkbox horizontal and vertical walls
repair_kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
repair = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel1, iterations=1)
repair_kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
repair = cv2.morphologyEx(repair, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel2, iterations=1)

# Detect checkboxes using shape approximation and aspect ratio filtering
checkbox_contours = []
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(repair, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.035 * peri, True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    aspect_ratio = w / float(h)
    if len(approx) == 4 and (aspect_ratio >= 0.8 and aspect_ratio <= 1.2):
        cv2.rectangle(original, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
        checkbox_contours.append(c)

print('Checkboxes:', len(checkbox_contours))
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('repair', repair)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Show your input and output results. We cannot test your code without your input image.